# Convert CHM to ebook for kindle 3

Tags: ebooks, kindle

Is there any application for Ubuntu that can convert CHM files to ebook compatible with kindle?

Answer (score 5):

### Calibre

I've been using Calibre for converting formats to my Kindle. I've not actually tested with a CHM, so please leave a comment with your results.

To install calibre in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install calibre
```

Comment: works out of shelf for me: but my chm had no images (except the cover and that got handled properly).

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/chm2mobi/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using **Calibre** for this matter but it doesn't seem to be very clear (maybe it's just me). I tend to get dizzy with so many options.

`chm2mobi` doesn't quite get there (at least it doesn't ask for so many options). I get a mobi but with warnings: links and images are not quite there.
To run it I'm editing filenames to remove any spaces in it (it doesn't handle them, as stated [in the script's site](http://code.google.com/p/chm2mobi/issues/detail?id=2)) and run it like:

`chm2mobi dir/and/filename.chm dir/and/filename.mobi`.

Anyone had better results with any of these? What options are you giving Calibre?